# Bold the 1st value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have to make the 1st value in the **dropdown** text to bold. I tried with `ng-class` attribute as the UI is developed in `angularjs` but didn't get success. Now, I am trying with `css` by making use of first-child selector. I tried with following styles.

```
1)
select#ad-version-select.form-control : first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}

2)
select#ad-version-select.form-control >: first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

But the above styles. didn't worked. If I use

```
select#ad-version-select.form-control {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

All values in **dropdown** are becoming bold. How to make only the 1st value in the **dropdown** to appear bold? I can't use `javascript` or `jquery`. Please help me with `css`.

Comment: did you try `option:first-child` ?

Comment: Tried but didn't worked..

Comment: The cross browser behaviour for styling options in a select dropdown are so inconsistent when using CSS. For example in Firefox making an item bold in the dropdown is possible, however in Chrome it is not, and this includes the optgroup. If styling these is important and you want cross browser consistency then you might consider a custom dropdown using divs for e.g.

Comment: In which case, if you can't use JavaScript (why?), then you can't do it cross-browser.

Comment: @Raevenk. I put the dropdown inside a div, and used the div classname along with the above classes I have mentioned. But its not working. Did you mean the samething?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
select#ad-version-select.form-control option:nth-child(1){
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44917&q=select%20styling%20bold&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified#makechanges

Comment: Yes. Works in firefox..!

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this-

```css
select#ad-version-select.form-control option:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="ad-version-select" class="form-control">
  <option value="">option</option>
  <option value="">option</option>
  <option value="">option</option>
  <option value="">option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select#ad-version-select.form-control option:nth-child(1) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

will do the job but it works only in firefox and not in google chrome or in safari.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can't bold the options.

The only method to highlight or bold is make it an option group

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Label Group">
       <option value="label value 1">Label 1</option>
       <option value="Label value 2">Label 2</option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup label="Label Group 2">
       <option value="label value 3">Label 3</option>
       <option value="label value 4">Label 4</option>
     </optgroup>
</select>
```

You can try here [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup)

Comment: Here, I can't have group as all the values in dropdown belongs to a single type. Is it not possible to have a single bold value in the dropdown?

Comment: By default the option value doesn't supports font weight bold. But you can use pseudo class for coloring the value.